# Magento 2 - How to loop all categories and load category image?

Tags: magento2

I'm building a theme for Magento 2. The homepage needs to loop through all the categories and output the category name, url and the image uploaded to the category within the admin within the .phtml file.

Is this possible and how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

I hope following code will help you.

We have used direct object manager. Please use this code in your phtml file and run anywhere.

```
<?php
//create a phtml file or write this code in any phtml file and use where you want

$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');

$categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$categories = $categoryHelper->getStoreCategories();
 
foreach ($categories as $category) { 
//print_r($category->getData()); ?>  
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl();?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ;?></a>
    
<?php }?>
```

Please check this link also -http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-parent-category-children-categories-product-count/